# Apache/php slow to respond to some clients

Tags: php, apache, http, raspberry-pi

I have inherited a demo with the server running on a Pi3 with apache2 and php5.

A gateway is trying to use html/php to update a database on the pi. It's a fairly simple operation and it seemed to work fine for a long time. This was before I was asked to look at it.

Recently however we are seeing some odd behaviors.

Specifically apache is not responding quickly to the embedded gateway (~5 seconds to HTTP OK is served).  However, if I try to run the same http via a browser or curl on another device on the network it responds instantly.  I have taken out all active scripting from the served page so it shouldn't be that.

I am wondering if the embedded gateway is not populating it's HTTP Get request properly.

Here is what the request looks like from the embedded gateway (that does not return for 5 seconds)

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET /demo/iot/updateScale.php?sensordata=5947 HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET /demo/iot/updateScale.php?sensordata=5947 HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [GET /demo/iot/updateScale.php?sensordata=5947 HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: GET
        Request URI: /demo/iot/updateScale.php?sensordata=5947
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Host: 192.168.10.106\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64)\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://192.168.10.106/demo/iot/updateScale.php?sensordata=5947]
    [HTTP request 1/1]
    [Response in frame: 26392]
```

Here is what it looks like from a samsung tablet that appears to be working correctly.

```
Hypertext Transfer Protocol
    GET /demo/iot/updateScale.php?sensordata=100 HTTP/1.1\r\n
        [Expert Info (Chat/Sequence): GET /demo/iot/updateScale.php?sensordata=100 HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [GET /demo/iot/updateScale.php?sensordata=100 HTTP/1.1\r\n]
            [Severity level: Chat]
            [Group: Sequence]
        Request Method: GET
        Request URI: /demo/iot/updateScale.php?sensordata=100
        Request Version: HTTP/1.1
    Host: 192.168.10.106\r\n
    Connection: keep-alive\r\n
    Cache-Control: max-age=0\r\n
    Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8\r\n
    User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 5.0.2; SM-T530NU Build/LRX22G) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/43.0.2357.93 Safari/537.36\r\n
    Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, sdch\r\n
    Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8\r\n
    \r\n
    [Full request URI: http://192.168.10.106/demo/iot/updateScale.php?sensordata=100]
    [HTTP request 1/1]
    [Response in frame: 23611]
```

Comment: This sounds more like a networking issue than a coding issue.

Comment: Have you ruled out general internet slowness? How long has this been happening? (if the gateway is ON the same internal network... could be faulty switch?) -edit- And yeah, doesnt sound like a php coding issue at all.

Comment: And your GET url specifies different values for sensordata.  Could it be that the processing time is different, or the returned data set is bigger?

Comment: Yes I don't think it is php specific. I have actually removed all php from the served page and it still behaves this way.  I left it tagged php in case it was related to php/apache interaction.

Comment: 5 seconds is probably some kind of 'pseudo-networking' issue, like a DNS lookup failure, ipV4 vs ipV6, other similar. Since your apache/php is constant (i assume) ... look elsewhere.

Comment: very strange I ran all of it fine on a pi2 just now and it seems to be working ok.  I assume you guys/girls are right and there is some networking issue failing that the pi3 is responding to differently.